# Fullscreen canvas not showing entire image

Tags: javascript, html

So i am trying to display a fullscreen image on a canvas (Minus the 80px header) but the canvas is playing up and not showing the entire thing.

Javascript

```
var c =document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();


img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    c.style.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    c.style.height = document.body.clientHeight-80;
};
img.src = "lol.gif";
```

And here is what lol.gif should [Look like](https://gyazo.com/9b5c6e9f86d95ce2ea4bb1269e955033)

However, this is what it does [look like](https://gyazo.com/0a58ceb36a1468d8618d6d6a30cfeee9) on the site. That purple bar should be there, thats the nav bar (When i make it)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, canvas doesn't take the same size as the window.
Try setting canvas width and height like this:

```
ctx.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.height = window.innerHeight;
```

or maybe

```
ctx.width = document.body.clientWidth; 
ctx.height = document.body.clientHeight;
```

if that's what you prefer. Depends on the browser, see

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp

Also, you might need to remove some css defaults by overriding:

```
html, body, canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```